# Getting "NotAuthorizedException Incorrect username or password" For Custom Auth Flow

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a password less SMS OTP based login using the custom auth flow. The custom challenge is passing but in the end i am getting not authorised error.

I have followed this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/implementing-passwordless-email-authentication-with-amazon-cognito/
Below is my php client code to respondToAuthChallenge

```
$response = $this->client->respondToAuthChallenge([
                    'ChallengeName' => 'CUSTOM_CHALLENGE',
                    'ChallengeResponses' => [
                        'USERNAME'     => $username,
                        'SECRET_HASH'  => $this->cognitoSecretHash($username),
                        "ANSWER"=>$otp
                    ],
                    'ClientId' => $this->clientId, // REQUIRED
                    'UserPoolId' => $this->poolId,
                    'Session' => $session
                ]);
```